# How do I test that my ConfigureHowToFindSaga is working in NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I realized today, the hard way, that the saga testing doesn't uses the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga`. This results in "Saga not found" exception showing up in production since my test doesn't cover the mapping, which I think it should. I have created a really simple example saga illustrating the problem:

```
public class MySpecialSaga : Saga<MySagaData>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<StartMessage>,
    IHandleMessages<NextMessage>
{
    public void Handle(StartMessage message)
    {
        Data.SagaId = message.Id;
        Console.WriteLine("Saga started with id: " + message.Id);
    }

    public void Handle(NextMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling next message with id: " + message.Id);
        Bus.Send(new StartMessage() {Id = message.Id + 1});
    }
}

public class NextMessage : ICommand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class StartMessage : ICommand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MySagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Originator { get; set; }
    public string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }
    public int SagaId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the following two tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MySpecialSagaTests
{
    public MySpecialSagaTests()
    {
        Test.Initialize();
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenSagaDoesNotExistItShouldNotFindSaga()
    {
        Test.Saga<MySpecialSaga>()
            .ExpectNotSend<StartMessage>(m => m.Id == 2)
            .When(s => s.Handle(new NextMessage() {Id = 1}));
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenSagaDoesExistItShouldFindSaga()
    {
        Test.Saga<MySpecialSaga>()
            .When(s => s.Handle(new StartMessage(){ Id = 1}))
            .ExpectNotSend<StartMessage>(m => m.Id == 2)
            .When(s => s.Handle(new NextMessage() {Id = 1}));
    }
}
```

The first one should fail, or at least not send the message, since it shouldn't be able to find the saga. The second test should pass when I've added the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` method. For some reason when testing sagas this is not considered. This can result in one having handlers in a saga that will not be executed due to a missing mapping.

How should this scenario be tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for unit testing mappings as of now. The strict mode mentioned here will support this type of testing.

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/654

Comment: I think that would be a really useful feature.

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund Any progress on this feature? It's not clear from the issue how this will help with unit testing mappings, or if this is actually available yet or not