# NServiceBus unit testing ConfigureHowToFindSaga

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus5

I would like to test `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` method in my NServiceBus Saga. Just had what seems like an avoidable issue where I'd forgotten to put the Unique attribute on Saga Data.

I could use Moq or similar but it awkward to verify the unique constraints on the Saga.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681055/how-do-i-test-that-my-configurehowtofindsaga-is-working-in-nservicebus), I don't think NServiceBus 5 provides anything out of the box to test this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a convention test, to ensure all your `ContainSagaData` derived classes have at least one property with `[Unique]` attribute.

As this doesn't prove that the saga behaves correctly, the way to test the behavior is explained in details [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/testing/#testing-a-saga).